# Failed to move a 7z Archive, now it can’t be read, but there is a fragment left in the original location named .part

Tags: data-recovery, mv, archive, corruption

I was trying to move my old 7z archive from an older ext4 partition to my current one, but in the process it randomly seems to have cancelled. Not only does the new location possess an incomplete archive, which cant be read, but the old location has a `7z.part` file. Is it possible to somehow continue the moving process? I can't seem to figure it out simply from the file explorer's UI, but I was wondering if there might be a terminal command?

Using `ls` in the old directory shows the old 7z file, but its name seems to be red, and ls claims it cannot be read (I/O error). Using it in the new directory seems to also show it as red, but it doesn't have the same error

The old directory was ~/Documents/Archive/backup (on a different partition, as this was from an older installation of Linux)

```bsh
[frontear@frontear-net backup]$ ls
ls: cannot access 'OneDrive.7z': Input/output error
OneDrive.7z  OneDrive.7z.part
```

Although `ls` claims a OneDrive.7z exists here, it's actually not visible via the file explorer, even with hidden files enabled

The current directory is ~/Desktop/Archive/backup (my current Linux install)

```bsh
[frontear@frontear-net backup]$ ls
OneDrive.7z
```

In both commands, the OneDrive.7z is in a red color, which I take to mean something, probably in regards to it being corrupted

Running `fsck` from a Manjaro Live ISO yields no obvious signs of corruption. `/dev/sda2` is my current partition, whereas `/dev/sda3` is the old partition.

```bsh
[manjaro manjaro]$ sudo fsck /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.4 (23-Sep-2019)
/dev/sda2: clean, 738853/39223296 files, 76011466/156883968 blocks
[manjaro manjaro]# fsck /dev/sda3
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.4 (23-Sep-2019)
Superblock last write time is in the future.
        (by less than a day, probably due to the hardware clock being incorrectly set)
/dev/sda3: clean, 4362438/9715712 files, 18432430/38835968 blocks
```

Edit: Updated `fsck` at the request of Timothy Baldwin:

```bsh
[manjaro manjaro]# fsck -f /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.4 (23-Sep-2019)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 19400943 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower.  Optimize<y>? yes
Pass 1E: Optimizing extent trees
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/sda2: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sda2: 757397/39223296 files (0.5% non-contiguous), 80084462/156883968 blocks
[manjaro manjaro]# fsck -f /dev/sda3
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.4 (23-Sep-2019)
Superblock last mount time is in the future.
        (by less than a day, probably due to the hardware clock being incorrectly set)
Superblock last write time is in the future.
        (by less than a day, probably due to the hardware clock being incorrectly set)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda3: 4362438/9715712 files (0.1% non-contiguous), 18432430/38835968 blocks
```

Edit 2: Updated `ls` to `ls -l`:

```bsh
[frontear@frontear-net ~]$ cd ~/Documents/Archive/backup/
[frontear@frontear-net backup]$ ls -l
ls: cannot access 'OneDrive.7z': Input/output error
total 2168832
-????????? ? ?        ?                 ?            ? OneDrive.7z
-rw------- 1 frontear frontear 2220883968 Apr 30 06:46 OneDrive.7z.part
[frontear@frontear-net backup]$ cd ~/Desktop/Archive/backup/
[frontear@frontear-net backup]$ ls -l
total 2446952
-rw------- 1 frontear frontear 2220883968 Apr 29 23:13  OneDrive.7z
```

Edit 3: Added a `smartctl` check:

```bsh
[manjaro@manjaro ~]$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda | sed -n '/Threshold/,/^$/p'
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0004   142   142   000    Old_age   Offline      -       70
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   128   128   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       177 (Average 180)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2450
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0004   118   118   000    Old_age   Offline      -       33
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       23216
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2388
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2461
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2461
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   119   119   000    Old_age   Always       -       46 (Min/Max 20/53)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0012   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       23203
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       171426971200
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       228792438899
```

Edit 4: `badblocks` check

```bsh
[manjaro@manjaro ~]$ sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sda
Checking blocks 0 to 976762583
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done                                                 
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

Comment: `fsck` skipped checking the filesystems because they were flagged as clean, you need the `-f` option.

Comment: I've updated the question to include a `fsck -f` check, seems to be fine from what I can see

Comment: In Debian and Ubuntu archives are coloured red by `ls`. That fact the `fsck` found no problems but `ls` had trouble suggests an intermittent problem.

Comment: Frontear, please can you extend your `ls` showing the `7z` files to `ls -l`. I'm particularly interested in size, date, and link type (if any), but the remaining metadata is potentially useful

Comment: I have updated the question. It seems the `.part` file is totally gone, but the invisible fragment has data, seemingly similar to the partial move operation

Comment: Ugh. That looks one really unhappy disk. If you run `smartctl -a /dev/sda | sed -n '/Threshold/,/^$/p'` I suspect you'll get some errors for `Offline_Uncorrectable`, `Current_Pending_Sector`, `Reallocated_Sector_Ct`, etc. If so, this is a dying or dead disk. Care to post the results?

Comment: I've added the results, I'm not entirely sure whether they are actually erroring, but those keywords are visible. Thing is I've yet to actually have an issue with this disk, this is the only transfer that has failed. I was able to transfer far more data easily, and this was recently too

Comment: Thanks. Looks a good disk, but the corruption implied by that broken `ls -l` most definitely isn't right. And after the `fsck` definitely concerning.

Comment: Does a (read only) `badblocks` from your Live ISO show any errors?

Comment: None, I've added the output as confirmation

Comment: can you check if there is any dmesg / syslog / journalctl from the time this happened? usually when a filesystem goes kaput the kernel is verbose about it. but ofc when its the same as rootfs and the filesystem went readonly, the logs might not be saved. moving files normally does not create .part files, this may be something specific to your file explorer (which one?) or something else entirely. in the end there is not enough information to come up with a specific answer, recovery could go either way.

Comment: I've found a dmesg from `journalctl -k -b 4`, and found a line that sound suspicious. `INFO: task dolphin:567940 blocked for more than 122 seconds.`. I use KDE Dolphin as the file explorer, and used it's move functionality to try and move my files. The full dmesg output can be found here: https://puu.sh/FJAiR/23084f0fae.txt

Comment: @Frontear dolphin also does not create .part files as far as I can see, but there is fuse in the backtrace, so a fuse filesystem might be doing things. Which is weird because the only filesystem you specified in your question is ext4. Hope dolphin didn't try to fuse-7z it or something... not familiar enough with kde / file manager to answer.

Comment: Ah, KDE / kio has ".part" file renaming logic. "While a file is being uploaded its extension is ".part". When fully uploaded it is renamed to its real name." - but that should appear at target location, not source as far as I can tell

Comment: Interesting, well this `.part` is definitely at the source location and not the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a hunch what had happened (based on your dmesg).

- What happened during your move is that your Dolphin has crashed during the moving process.

  ```
  Apr 29 23:14:28 frontear-net kernel: dolphin         D    0 567940      1 0x00004084
  Apr 29 23:14:28 frontear-net kernel: Call Trace:  ...
  ```
- You have used some filesystem that needed [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) like NTFS, etc.  Which probably caused a deadlock (a wild guess a cache overflow or similar)
- If the original is damaged than it is a serious bug in Dolphin, FUSE, or the NTFS-3g driver you are probably using.

### Now to your original question

Out of curiosity could you execute:
`sudo chmod -R g+x ~/Documents/Archive/backup`?  I wonder what will happen.

It appears that the file you are trying to list is damaged, that is the reason why you are getting the error : `ls: cannot access 'OneDrive.7z': Input/output error`.  (from the actions you have taken it appears that the your HW is OK).  Your file system (journal?) appears to be damaged.  Before attempting fixing it I would **highly recommend** creating a disk image via e.g. ddrescue.

(*Note:* When doing a `fsck` don't forget that the filesystem must be `umount`(ed)!)

### The answer your question, if the copy process can be continued?

It can't because you are using the wrong tool for the task.

You should be using [**rsync**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) or similar tool to make sure you have correct copy of the original file.

### How to recover your bad 7z file?

The best bet is to follow these instructions - [How to recover corrupted 7z archive](https://www.7-zip.org/recover.html) from 7-zip.org.

### What to do better next time?

1) Use [**rsync**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) for copying, moving, etc important files

2) Split large files into more smaller files

3) When compressing use a recovery information - 7zip does not support adding the recovery information, but it can be added in a par1.0/par2.0 format. (for linux use [par2cmdline](https://github.com/parchive/par2cmdline) or gui [Easy Par2 for KDE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ekpar2/), for windows you can use [MultiPar](http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA021385/) or [MultiPar on Github](https://github.com/Yutaka-Sawada/MultiPar); [QuickPar](http://www.quickpar.org.uk/Tutorials.htm)).

4) For storage use advanced filesystems like zfs (with ECC RAM) to improve your data integrity

Comment: Running `sudo chmod -R g+x ~/Documents/Archive/backup` returns `chmod: cannot access '/home/frontear/Documents/Archive/backup/': Permission denied`

Comment: @Frontear  I thought so.  Well if you have another copy of the file I recommend using that one with rsync.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I presume the file is long gone. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Frontear you can try the recovery procedure for the 7zip which I have linked, which is an advanced procedure but still you have a chance. Otherwise than that you are out of luck. You are welcome.